# find all nested array in single array in python WITHOUT FLATTEN or any inbuilt function

Tags: python

Hi I need a single list of nested lists in python without any inbuilt function. I did a lot of research but not able to find without flatten or ravel function().

for ex:

```
input = [1,2,[2,3,[4,5]],[6,7],[8,[9]],10]
output = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: [The first solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) doesn't use any built-in functions.  Is this acceptable?

Comment: You can use recursion to implement your own `flatten` function.

Comment: @DarrylG This was not working

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists

Comment: You're right, that only works when all elements are lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **recursion** to implement your own flatten function. Here's a nice tutorial explaining the concepts of [recursion](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/).

The idea here is that you loop through each element in your list and if you encounter a sublist you recursively call the same method with the current list. If it's a valid element you add it to to your output list.

Example:

```py
def flatten(input_list, output_list=[]):

  for i in input_list:
    if isinstance(i, list):
      flatten(i, output_list)
    else:
      output_list.append(i)

  return output_list

input_list = [1,2,[2,3,[4,5]],[6,7],[8,[9]],10]

print(flatten(input_list))
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Would suggest changing function signature to: def flatten(input_list, output_list = []).  That way the user does not have to create or pass output on call.

Comment: @DarryIG, good spot. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on my own. Below is the solution:

```
c = []
def test(a):
    for val in a:
        if type(val) == list:
            test(val)
        else:
            c.append(val)
return c
```

a=[1,2,[2,3,[4,5]],[6,7],[8,[9]],10]
   print test(a)